# How to replace cursor code with CTE in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, common-table-expression

I have a condition where I need to pull id's from one master table and then based on that  value pull values from two different tables and then update/insert into third table with these values.

I am using cursor to loop through the records in master table however I feel like this is leading to performance issue. I wanted to know if this can be done using CTE or not. I tried using CTE but it is non recursive and I am totally lost where I am going wrong.

Here is how my stored procedure is -

```
//
BEGIN

declare @variables char(10);
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR; --DECLARE CURSOR
SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR -- SET CURSOR
    -- pull in value for curso
OPEN @cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @variables --FILL IN CURSOR TO LOOP THROUGH

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN

        BEGIN
            --PUll values from table 1
        END
        BEGIN
            --Pull values from table 1
            -- Do some maths on the values pulled
        END
        BEGIN
            --function/sql to  update or insert
        END 


    FETCH NEXT
        FROM @cursor INTO @variables;
    END
    CLOSE @cursor;
    DEALLOCATE @cursor;

END
//
```

With CTE, my code is -

```
//

;WITH CTE AS 
    (
    --pull values from master table
)


BEGIN
     BEGIN
         -- pull values from table 1
     END
 BEGIN
         -- Pull values from table 2, do the calculations
 END
 BEGIN
          -- insert or update as needed. 
 END
//
```

Comment: A key component to answering this question is what you are doing in this bit: **`-- Do some maths on the values pulled`** if you are just doing some maths on the variables row by row it is quite likely neither a CTE or a cursor are required and a simple update statement will suffice.

Comment: I am assigning the values from table1 and table 2 in variables and doing some calculations on that. Then the final value is saved in the third table. The id from the master table is common in all.

Comment: It sounds like a joined update statement will suffice. It hard to be sure without seeing your schema and exactly what your *calculations* are. Common table expressions are not functionally synonomous with cursors, each have their merits and their downfalls (cursors more so). A set based solution will almost always outperform procedural solutions.

Comment: You cannot do what you're trying to do. The CTE can be following by *exactly* one `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statement - not a whole block. So you need to get the data from tables 1 and 2 and the calculations done inside the CTE, and then you can call an `UPDATE` (or `MERGE`) statement on your ultimate table.